# Reading Serial Data from Arduino, Corrupted Data

Tags: c++, file-io, serial-port, arduino, serial-communication

I am using an Arduino Due and Visual Studio 2010. I am programming in C/C++. Below you see my programs and after this my explanations of what is going wrong.

This is the really simple code thats on my Arduino. Its sending a lot of A's to the PC.

```
void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println('A');
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

The further code for reading the Serial Port I found over here:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

And this is my modified version of this code at the moment:

### Header:

```
#ifndef SERIALCLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define SERIALCLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME 2000

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Serial
{
    private:
        //Serial comm handler
        HANDLE hSerial;
        //Connection status
        bool connected;
        //Get various information about the connection
        COMSTAT status;
        //Keep track of last error
        DWORD errors;

    public:
        //Initialize Serial communication with the given COM port
        Serial(char *portName);
        //Close the connection
        //NOTA: for some reason you can't connect again before exiting
        //the program and running it again
        ~Serial();
        //Read data in a buffer, if nbChar is greater than the
        //maximum number of bytes available, it will return only the
        //bytes available. The function return -1 when nothing could
        //be read, the number of bytes actually read.
        int ReadData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar);
        //Writes data from a buffer through the Serial connection
        //return true on success.
        bool WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar);
        //Check if we are actually connected
        bool IsConnected();
};

#endif // SERIALCLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

### CPP:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "SerialClass.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace System;
using namespace std;

// Serial::Serial looks, if Serial Connection from PC to the Device is proper and everything is working. Then it sets a few Parameters and waits
Serial::Serial(char *portName)
{
    //We're not yet connected
    this->connected = false;

    //Try to connect to the given port throuh CreateFile
    this->hSerial = CreateFileA(portName,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

    //Check if the connection was successfull
    //if not...show error
    if(this->hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //If not success full display an Error
        if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
            //Print Error if neccessary
            printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available.\n", portName);
            Sleep(2000);
        }
        else
        {printf("ERROR!!!");}
    }
    // else = connection is working, then -> continue
    else
    {
        //If connected we try to set the comm parameters
        DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};

        //Try to get the current Parameters
        if (!GetCommState(this->hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
        {
            //If impossible, show an error
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Define serial connection parameters for the arduino board

            dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
            dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
            dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;


             //Set the parameters and check for their proper application
             if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
             {
                printf("ALERT: Could not set Serial Port parameters");
             }
             else
             {
                 //If everything went fine we're connected
                 this->connected = true;
                 //We wait 2s as the arduino board will be reseting
                 Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
             }
        }
    }
}


//Has a look if SerialPort is still connected.
//If yes, it disconnects and closes the Serial Handler.
Serial::~Serial()
{
    //Check if we are connected before trying to disconnect
    if(this->connected)
    {
        //We're no longer connected
        this->connected = false;
        //Close the serial handler
        CloseHandle(this->hSerial);
    }
}


// reads data out of Serial Port
int Serial::ReadData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    //Number of bytes we'll have read
    DWORD bytesRead;
    //Number of bytes we'll really ask to read
    unsigned int toRead;

    //Use the ClearCommError function to get status info on the Serial port
    ClearCommError(
        this->hSerial, // Handle to the communications device, CreateFile Function returns this value
        &this->errors, // a pointer to a variable that receives a mask indicating the type of rror
        &this->status);// a pointer to a COMSTAT structure in which the devices status information is returned. if this parameter is NULL, no status information is returned

//Check if there is something to read
if(this->status.cbInQue>0) // cbInQue: Number of Bytes received by the Serial provider, but not yet read by a ReadFile operation
{
    //If there is we check if there is enough data to read the required number
    //of characters, if not we'll read only the available characters to prevent
    //locking of the application.
    if(this->status.cbInQue>nbChar)
        {toRead = nbChar;}
    else
        {toRead = this->status.cbInQue;}

    //Try to read the require number of chars, and return the number of read bytes on success
    if(ReadFile(
       this->hSerial,   // Handle to a device
       buffer,          // a pointer to the buffer that receives the data read from a file or device
       toRead,          // NumberofBytesToRead: the maximum number of bytes to be read
       &bytesRead,      // NumberofBytesRead: a pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronours hFile parameter.
            NULL)           // Overlapped
            && bytesRead    // Value of bytesRead after ReadFile function
            != 0)
        {return bytesRead;
        Sleep(1000);}   // returns Value of BytesRead
    }
    //If nothing has been read, or that an error was detected return -1
    return -1;
}



bool Serial::IsConnected() // simply returns connection status
{
    //Simply return the connection status
    return this->connected;
}
```

### Main:

```
// application reads from the specified serial port and reports the collected data
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
     printf("Welcome to the serial test app!\n\n");
     Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM3");    // adjust as needed

     if (SP->IsConnected())
        printf("We're connected");

     // defines how much Data will be catched
     // don't forget to pre-allocate memory

        char incomingData[1025] = "";
        incomingData[1024]='\0';

        int dataLength = 1024; // maximum Length of one DataBit/Word
        int readResult = 0;

        // gives out the Number! of DataBits that could be collected/catched
        readResult = SP->ReadData(incomingData,dataLength);

        printf("Bytes read: (-1 means no data available) %i\n",readResult);


        // transforms the char incomingData into a String and prints it

        std::string test(incomingData);
        printf("%s \n", incomingData);

        printf("Bytes read: (-1 means no data available) %i\n",readResult);

        Sleep(10000);
   }
```

So now here is my problem:

The programm works fine, as long as the Amount of Bits I am sending from the Arduino is less than DataLength. (here = 1024) I got those less bits just through setting the Delay from the Arduino programm quite high (~100ms).
Then I have a console window with an Output similar to this:

```
A
A
A
A
A
... goes on like this
```

But if the Arduino sends more than 1024 Bits (Delay ~ 1ms)/ the PC receices more Bits than the Value of DataLength, something in the Serial::ReadData Loop seems to get wrong.
My Console Output is than a little bit corrupted and some Bits look like this:

```
A
ßA

A A
A
... goes on similar to this.
```

What is wrong with my program? I thought that it could be, that one parameter of the ReadFile() Function is not right, but I do not know what to change and I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: Can you show some output with your debug `readResult` statement in it?

Comment: If I only send less Bits than DataLength(1024), ReadResult gets f.e. 500 or any other Number less than 1024, so it's right. If I got more Data than 1024, the Value of ReadResult always gets 1024. Is that what you mean?